# Why is the time before 1892 printed incorrectly in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I came across a weird date behaviour in Swift.

If I try to print any date before 1891, the minutes and seconds will be printed incorrectly with offset by 2 minutes and 16 seconds like this:

**Code Sample:**

```
// incorrectly printed date
let year1981 = Calendar.current.date(from: .init(year: 1891, hour: 9))
print(year1981!) // will print 1891-01-01 08:02:16 +0000

// correctly printed date
let year1982 = Calendar.current.date(from: .init(year: 1892, hour: 9))
print(year1982!) // will print 1892-01-01 08:00:00 +0000
```

Is there any rational reason for this behaviour or it is a bug? Thanks for any reply!

*Tested in Xcode Playground 14.1*

Comment: What is your current calendar? Gregorian? Chinese? etc.

Comment: My current Calendar is Gregorian. If I print the formatted date like: "print(year1982!.formatted())" it prints correctly without 2 minutes and 16 seconds shift. But without formatted() function, each date before 1892 is printed shifted by 2 minutes and 16 seconds.

Comment: When I run your code in an Xcode 14.2 macOS or iOS playground I see the time as 16:00:00 +0000 (I'm in the GMT-7 timezone so that's correct), not as 08:02:16 +0000. What timezone are you in? Maybe your timezone had some strange adjustment back in 1891 so the conversion to GMT (+0000) appears odd.

Comment: Okay, that is really strange. Thank you for the advice. It seems like it has something to do with timezones. I have tried to set several different timezones on my mac and the offset for each timezone is different. For London timezone (GMT +00:00) it is printed correctly, but for Prague (GMT +01:00) it is shifted by 2 minutes and 16 seconds. But I have noticed that the offset varies according to different timezones. Thank you again for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments you are in the "Europe/Prague" timezone.

According to [this website information](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/czech-republic/prague?year=1891):

> When local standard time was about to reach
> Thursday, October 1, 1891, 12:00:00 midnight clocks were turned forward 0:02:16 hours to
> Thursday, October 1, 1891, 12:02:16 am local standard time instead.

This change would explain the results you are seeing when converting such a date.

So it is not a bug. It's just one of many examples of how complicated Date and Calendar code is due to all of the obscure details of time zones and day light saving time can be.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you for the explanation! Dates and calendar types are really complex topic.